# How do I print my Java RenderingHints desktophints?

Tags: java, fonts, maps, awt, antialiasing

I know that the following code gives a map, but I don't know how to print the values

```
Map<?,?> hints = (Map<?,?>)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints");
```

I want to figure out how to print out each desktophint key and value so I can tell what RenderingHints I get from the map.

Comment: `System.out.println(hints);` is sufficient.  All Java SE `Map` implementations have a toString method that displays all of the keys with their corresponding values.

Comment: There’s always `hints.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v));`.

Comment: It works, but the output isn't too straightforward. What I get is:  ```{Text-specific antialiasing enable key=LCD HRGB antialiasing text mode, Text-specific LCD contrast key=120}``` which represents: ```RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB``` ```RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_LCD_CONTRAST, 120``` . Still, I didn't expect an intelligible output from using toString on a Map.

Comment: What does forEach do?

Comment: Prints a single key/value pair per line, in this case.  If you’re trying to get the exact RenderingHints constants, more code is needed, but how important is that?  You clearly know exactly what the string form of each key and non-numeric value signifies.